# how to build / compile ndk application?

Tags: android, android-ndk

hi now i am download ndk but i dont know how to build and compile actually i am new for android application....now i am using linux...and i am not well in command line....

```
embdes@embdes-laptop:~$ cd /home/embdes/projects/android/android-sdk-linux_86
/platform-tools/
embdes@embdes-laptop:~/projects/android/android-sdk-linux_86/platform-tools$ 
./adb shell 
# ls
config
cache
sdcard
acct
mnt
d
etc
system
sys
sbin
proc
init.rc
init.goldfish.rc
init
default.prop
data
root
dev
# cd /sdcard
# ls
LOST.DIR
unnai.mp3
car.3gp
DCIM
cheetah-.3gp
funny.3gp
tshirt.3gp
Girl.3gp
dancing.3gp
b7.jpeg
girl1.3gp
tv.3gp
sports.3gp
sports1.3gp
sports3.3gp
sport2.3gp
tv.jpeg
tv1.jpeg
global.jpeg
orange.jpeg
images.jpeg
ddddd.jpeg
balloons-lift-car.3gp
3d-little-monster.3gp
smoking.3gp
the.3gp
NO$GBA.2.6a.zip
worldreborn.bin
#
```

Comment: I recommend using eclipse, will fix you issues.

Comment: There is a more concise answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460251/how-do-i-build-a-native-command-line-executable-to-run-on-android

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read getting started here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

also look at samples they explained here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#samples

Here: [android/ndk-tutorial/](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/ndk-tutorial/) you will find a tutorial on working with NDK in android.

TO use NDK with eclipse look at here: [eclipse-and-android-ndk](http://mobilebytes.wordpress.com/2010/09/25/eclipse-and-android-ndk/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually i am not very well in command line...1st how to install ndk in eclipse now i am downloaded ndk and unzip that package...if u dont mine please tell me step by step...i will follow you....

Comment: @bala: the link android/ndk-tutorial contains step by step information. just go through it.

Comment: ok my doubt is how to set path where is the native path settings...if i ask any stupid questions...sorry help me....

Answer (score 3):

1. Download and install ndk

   You can install Ndk from https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html
   At the time of writing ndk-r10e was the latest version and i was on linux 64 bits so i downloaded this -
   **android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.bin**

2 after downloading you need to install it

change the permissions

```
chmod a+x android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.bin
```

execute

```
./android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.bin
```

3 add it to path on linux

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/android-ndk-r10e
```

4. To run a sample application use hello-jni under samples
   [image]

5.goto the project location from terminal and ndk-build

```
ndk-build
```

[image]

6. Run the application in emulator to see results
   [image]

Comment: I got  dirname: command not found. and userRD/Sample/build/ndk-build: No such file or directory. How can I solved that. First I execute  this in my app terminal  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214835/error-in-ndk-build-command-on-terminal-mac and then run ndk-build
. and also run  /Users/Admin/Documents/RD/Sample/build//ndk-build APP_PLATFORM=android-8 . Showing above error. Please help me . mmaid786@gmail.com this is my email id.