# Run a native C program on unrooted Android device

Tags: android, c

I've managed to build a native executable for Android, after reading [How do I build a native (command line) executable to run on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460251/how-do-i-build-a-native-command-line-executable-to-run-on-android), but I can't execute it on my unrooted phone, it gives

> /system/bin/sh: /storage/sdcard0/Download/hello_world: can't execute: Permission denied

because the SD card is mounted with `noexec`, and I can't write anywhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me - it seems that `/data/local/tmp` is writable, and it isn't on a `noexec` partition.

The solution requires using `adb`. I connected the phone through USB, and I enabled USB debugging from developer options.

Then I uploaded the file to the phone using:

```
adb push C:\Workspace\hello_world\libs\armeabi\hello_world /data/local/tmp/hello_wo
rld
```

Then I ran adb shell:

```
adb shell
```

And from it I changed the write permission, and ran it:

```
chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/hello_world
/data/local/tmp/hello_world
```