# How to compile and install native Linux software for Android without cross-compiling?

Tags: android, c, linux

Now I have root shell access to an Android platform. It's very much like working on a *normal* embedded Linux platform like Raspberry Pi. But the key difference is I haven't found a way to install or compile *Linux software* for it. Here the *software* doesn't mean Android apps. I just want the normal Linux software such as gcc, python, etc.

Firstly, is there a similar command to `apt-get` that I can use for installing Linux software/applications?

If there is not, I have to compile the software from the source code. Where can I find a proper *native* gcc toolchain for Android? I do not want to use cross-compiling like in this question ( [How do I build a native (command line) executable to run on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460251/how-do-i-build-a-native-command-line-executable-to-run-on-android)).

BTW, my Android platform is not a phone or tablet. It's a dev kit with ARM Cortex A9 cores.

Comment: Maybe Lil' Debi? https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=deb&fdid=info.guardianproject.lildebi or Debian Kit: https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=deb&fdid=org.dyndns.sven_ola.debian_kit

Comment: @kestasx Thanks. Lil' Debi looks good. I can accept your answer if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible options:

- [Lil' Debi](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=deb&fdid=info.guardianproject.lildebi)
- [Debian Kit](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=deb&fdid=org.dyndns.sven_ola.debian_kit)

Both these tools provide native toolchain in chroot environment.