# Unable to run c++ executable from Android terminal emulator

Tags: android, c++

Following the instruction of [How do I build a native (command line) executable to run on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460251/how-do-i-build-a-native-command-line-executable-to-run-on-android), I can build a C++ command line program that can run in Android. I use `adb push ./hello_world /data/local/tmp/hello_world` to install the program on Android device. It seems to work fine when I run the following commands in Linux:

```
adb shell chmod 777 /data/local/tmp/hello_world
adb shell /data/local/tmp/hello_world
```

After that, I come to the real Android device (NEXUS), and try to run it from the Terminal Emulator in the device. However, after being in /data/local/tmp folder, running hello_world gives me the following error:

```
/system/bin/sh hello_world not found.
```

Any ideas?