# Running a C binary from an android application : particulare case

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I have a C project that I want to launch on Android.

I compiled the project using the NDK, generate the binary and embed it in an application to launch it.
The project uses autotools, I used [androgenizer](https://git.collabora.com/cgit/android/androgenizer.git/tree/README.txt) to generate and adapt the `Android.mk`s.
It also uses openssl, so I compiled it for android following [this](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android#OpenSSL_Library), and binary uses compiled `libcrypto.so`.

The application only does :

- Load the libcrypto.so
- Copy the binary
- Execute the binary

Here is a piece of code

```
Process mybinProcess;
File target = new File(getFilesDir(), "mybin");
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mybin);

try {
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(target);
    FileUtils.copy(in, out);
    FileUtils.chmod(target, 0755);

if(target.exists()){
    String[] command = {target.getAbsolutePath()};
    mybinProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    BufferedReader output = FileUtils.getOuput(mybinProcess);
    BufferedReader error = FileUtils.getError(mybinProcess);

    // [...] print stdout et stderr

    mybinProcess.waitFor();
    int exitval=mybinProcess.exitValue(); //exit value is 1
```

The stdout gives me a syntax error on the binary :

```
/data/data/com.myproject.mybin/files/mybin[1]: syntax error: ' 4   4' unexpected
```

And when I tried to launch the binary from the adb shell, got that error

```
root@generic_x86:/data/user/0/com.myproject/files # ./mybin
/system/bin/sh: ./mybin: not executable: 32-bit ELF file
```

I opened `mybin` in an hex editor, the syntax error comes before the string of the lib `/usr/lib/libc.so.1`. But on the emulator the directory `/usr` doesn't exist. I think it comes from the ndk, the last compilation line of the `ndk-build` make an include from `<ndk>/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib`. Besides, in `<ndk>/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib` there is only `libc.so` and not `libc.so.1`.

Any idea on where I can search to fix it, make it works?

---

My configuration  :

- NDK : r11c
- Android platform : 19
- Android Studio : 2.1
- SDK : r24.4.1
- `mybin` (ndk) compiled on Linux and the apk (Android Studio) on Windows

Answer (score 4):

Building an executable to run on Android is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460251/how-do-i-build-a-native-command-line-executable-to-run-on-android), but not the right approach IMO, You should build a JNI interface to your native binary library and make calls into the C library.

There is a simple example here:

http://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni.html

We have had a lot of success using [javacpp](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) to generate the JNI code if you have a lot of JNI calls.  If you need only one or two calls, I'd probably write it by hand.

Comment: If I uses my C code as a library, I have to rewrite the whole project in Java. I want to launch the binary directly on the Android, and following the ndk build executable instruction it generated me an unusable executable...

Comment: @raja.b `If I uses my C code as a library, I have to rewrite the whole project in Java` I'm not sure I follow you.  I'd suggest leaving the C code as-is, but instead of building the C code as an executable, create a C library with one or two methods to get data from the library.  Then create the same JNI methods on the java side to interface with it.  Much easier than dealing with the command interface and scraping text from the output.  If you ever do get that working, but may not work that well on all devices.

Comment: @GaryBack `Much easier than dealing with the command interface and scraping text from the output. `. For the moment, there is no need to deal with text output. This is a further step, after making the binary run, using the java side to interface will be the best option. The thing I am not understanding is the fact that a binary generated by the ndk is not compatible (32-bit error, syntax error) with the targeted platform.