# Error in ndk-build command on terminal (Mac)

Tags: android, android-ndk

Here comes  my environment variable setting in (.bashrc)..

```
export ANDROID_SDK="/AndroidSDK/android-sdks"
export ANDROID_NDK="/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r8d"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROIDNDK"
```

when i try to run ndk-build on ternimal it display error message saying

```
-bash: ndk-build: command not found
```

i am just try to build San Angeles  sample example in ndk directory.

Comment: after executing source ~/.bashrc command.android sdk works perfectly for example adb,ddms,android etc.but when i try to execute ndk-build it give me error message "-bash: ndk-build: command not found".Kindly help me out .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you are supplying wrong value in `PATH` variable, you have declared `ANDROID_NDK` as `Environment`, and in `PATH` variable you are adding **`ANDROIDNDK`** ( you are missing `_` under score. )

Please edit your lines as below,

```
export ANDROID_SDK="/AndroidSDK/android-sdks"
export ANDROID_NDK="/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r8d"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROID_NDK"
```