# How to change the size of the video in ARMovieProj (ARToolkit)

Tags: android, video, artoolkit

I am new to ARToolkit and I try to use the ARMovieProj from the examples (Android Studio Projects). 
https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5/tree/master/AndroidStudioProjects/ARMovieProj

I am able to change the NFT marker in the marker.dat

```
# Number of markers
1

# Entries for each marker. Format is:
#
# Name of pattern file (relative to this file)
# Marker type (SINGLE)
# Marker width in millimetres (floating point number)
# Optional tokens:
#     FILTER [x]   Enable pose estimate filtering for the preceding marker
#                  x (optional) specifies the cutoff frequency. Default
#                  value is AR_FILTER_TRANS_MAT_CUTOFF_FREQ_DEFAULT, which
#                  at time of writing, equals 5.0.
# A blank line

../DataNFT/markerkanji
NFT
FILTER 15.0
```

also the video displayed in the ARMovieActivity

```
 private static final String movieFile = "Data/myvideo.mp4";
```

But the problem is the size of the video when it appears on screen. It's too small.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aJH4.png)

I tried changing all the sizes I saw in the project but I am unable to enlarge the video. I can't find a solution online either.

The video itself is 1280*720.

Does someone knows how to do?

Comment: I updated to hiro.patt but it start giving error. Can you share the changes you done?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the video is projected using perspective projection theory. That means it creates a matrix that is used for projection of video on marker. So, all you have to do is find the line in the code where the scale factor is used, like in the below code snippet.

```
 Filename : ARMovie.cpp
// We have a new pose, so set that.
arglCameraViewRHf(markersNFT[i].trans, markersNFT[i].pose.T, 0.25f /*VIEW_SCALEFACTOR*/);
// Tell any dependent objects about the update.
//ARMarkerUpdatedPoseNotification
```

All you have to do is change the last arg of this function call according to your need i.e.  (0.25f /*VIEW_SCALEFACTOR*/) and build the jni part.

Comment: I tried several values for the view scalefactor variable but the output videos size didn't change. :/

Comment: Try building the **JNI** part separately using **NDK**.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: [Refer both answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849565/how-to-build-compile-ndk-application)